# Print empty list in Haksell

Tags: haskell, empty-list

Here is the piece of code:

```
import System.Environment 
myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse [] = []
main = print (myReverse [])
```

When I compile that with GHC I get the following error:

> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( problem5_myReverse.hs, problem5_myReverse.o )
>       problem5_myReverse.hs:6:8:
>       No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `print'
>       The type variable`a0' is ambiguous
>       Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
>       Note: there are several potential instances:
>         instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
>         instance Show Float -- Defined in`GHC.Float'
>         instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
>           -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
>         ...plus 23 others
>       In the expression: print (myReverse [])
>       In an equation for`main': main = print (myReverse [ ])

But when I change the signature from `myReverse::[a]->[a]` to `myReverse::[Int]->[Int]` the source code is compiled without any problems

Can somebody tell how can I keep the general signature `[a] -> [a]` but make it work for empty Integer lists?

Comment: `main = print []` will evoke the exact same error. Your function has nothing to do with it. `print` needs a concrete type such as `Int` or `[Int]` or ... (anything of class `Show`). But all it has is `[a]` because the list is empty and its elements could potentially be of any type.

Comment: As a side note, it actually does matter. The way `[]` prints is actually different if it has type `[Char]` than if it has type `[Int]`, for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `myReverse []` (or `[]` in general), it is not possible to for the type inferencer to infer to list element type because it's an empty list. If you explicitly call e.g. `myReverse ([] :: [Int])`, it'll be able to find a `Show` instance for the list so that it can convert it to string before printing.

This is because the `Show` instance for lists is defined with `Show a => Show [a]` meaning that `[a]` only has a `Show` instance for it if `a` has a `Show` instance for it. But there is no `a` to start with in the case of `[]`.

Comment: My guess is that 'putStr "[]"' would work even better.