# Print empty list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is haskell code. I'm finding why I am wrong with below.

```
main = do
    print [1] -- Okay
    print [] -- error
```

Error strings are following.

> P07.hs:38:11: error:
>       ? Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
>         prevents the constraint ‘(Show t0)’ from being solved.
>         Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
>         These potential instances exist:
>           instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
>           instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
>           instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
>           ...plus 22 others
>           ...plus five instances involving out-of-scope types
>           (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
>       ? In a stmt of a 'do' block: print []
>         In the expression: do { print [] }
>         In an equation for ‘main’: main = do { print [] }

I tried `[] :: Show` not working. I think I just don't know what the errors mean.. please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23611674/382982) answer.

Answer (score 5):

Lists in Haskell are polymorphic in their element's type and as `[]` contains not enough information you have to supply ghc with it by explicitly giving a type annotation `[] :: [Int]` for example.

The error you are getting is due to the fact that the `Show` instance for lists is depending on the `Show` instance for its elements, and as ghc cannot determine that it assumes that ist has no such instance.

Now you might think everything can be converted to a `String`, but then you could think of `Int -> Int` and try

```
show [(+1)]
```

Which will not work as functions in Haskell have no default `Show` instance.

Comment: Thanks. It works with `main = do ([] :: [Int])`

Comment: I think it shouldn't work like that, I think you are missing a `print`

Comment: Yes, I failed. `main = do print ([] :: [Int])` is right. Thanks again.